# Guitar slur. Need help on understanding notations

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, notation

I'm new to the guitar so I'm stumbled upon this and am confused. I think that the curve connecting the 11th fret and 10th fret means a slur? Did some research myself and found out that a slur can mean hammer on, pull off, bending and slide...
So how do I play the 11th fret G string and 10th fret B string? I am not sure about the last portion as well. Can anyone guide me on this? Thank you.

[image: Tab image]

Answer (score 1):

As these are on two different strings the most likely option is a hammer on to the 10th fret.

The other options: a hammer on then slide, or a hammer and bend should indicate the initial note followed by the final one.

Try the hammer on and see what it sounds like - as with anything in music, there are many ways to play anything, so it could depend on the style of the artist.

Answer (score 1):

I think we'd need to see the staff notation to be certain. It appears to me that the same curve notation is being used for several different things in this passage.

In the second measure (the one you ask about), it looks to me like it should be a sweep-pick. Fret the (E-shape) D chord and pick the notes in one direction. The F♯ should ring-through the A.

In the fourth measure, that's definitely a pull-off.

In the fifth measure, the two connected F♯s could be tied, or the second could be more of a ghost note. Then there's a pull-off + sweep.

In all of these uses, the curve appears to indicate phrasing more than specific effects. Usually, you'd refer to the staff notation to clarify what the tab means. For a (slide) slur there's usually an angled line directly between the two notes indicate the direction to slide (aka glissando or glis.).

Comment: I agree. For the O.P.: strictly speaking hammers, pulls etc. are *technical slurs* and can be notated with the same curved line as *phrasing slurs* which simply means to play the notes so that they go together smoothly

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on what you are trying to play, its too vague to just give us the tab and let us guess, as most times on music, tablature isnt sufficient nor it should be, every musician must have his own interpretation of the tablature and of the song itself, if you're playing a cover and want to play exactly like on the record, listen to it and just play like the original, you will notice if it is a bend, a hammer on, a slide or a pull off...

By just looking at the tab, I would say that the best thing to do there would be to slide, like, you hold the note on the 10th fret G String and slide into the 11th on the B.

You can also try to hold the 10th G (I would use my index finger) and slide with another finger (here I would slide with the middle finger) to the 11th B, but then again, I dont know the song and I cant help you much further with this, it isnt just a simple "I dont know what this symbol means" it's the interpretation of the symbol and how it interacts with the song.

Bottom line: Just listen to the song and try multiple options until you get the one that sounds right

Hope this helped, happy playing :)

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers are wrong, but one consideration is that the tab is "incorrect" and the 11th fret on the G ought to be the 7th fret on the B.

In this case, the first 2 measures might be (B string) 7-5|7-slide to-10

Of course, the overall context matters here, so it may or may not make sense depending on what comes earlier.